# Debug constraints when setting view programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a complex set of labels and buttons. I set everything programmatically using mainly visual format language. The UILabels are created with the following method:

```
-(UILabel*)createLabelWithPlaceHolder:(NSString*)placeHolder{

    UILabel *provisionalLabel=[[UILabel alloc] init];

    provisionalLabel =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    provisionalLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    provisionalLabel.text=placeHolder;
    provisionalLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    provisionalLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    provisionalLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [provisionalLabel setContentHuggingPriority:200 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [provisionalLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:900 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

    return provisionalLabel;
}
```

and the labels are displayed according to the following VLF code:

```
gap=(self.vistaGris.bounds.size.width*secondRowFactor)/7;
labelWidth=(self.vistaGris.bounds.size.width*(1-secondRowFactor))/6;

gapN=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:gap];
labelWidthN=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:labelWidth];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-gap-[solution4(width)]-gap-[solution5(width)]-gap-[solution6(width)]-gap-[solution7(width)]-gap-[solution8(width)]-gap-[solution9(width)]-gap-|"
                                                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                      metrics:@{@"gap":gapN, @"width":labelWidthN}
                                                        views:viewsDictionary];

[self.vistaGris addConstraints:constraints];
```

Basically what it does is to display 6 labels on the bottom of the view. With equal spaces between them and same width. The device orientation is always landscape all the time.

The code does what I want it to do and everything is displayed OK. However I got a console warning telling me that the system cannot satisfy simultaneous constraints:

```
2014-04-19 09:59:48.749 Concentrations[431:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d6cd70 Linees:0x8c82d70.width == UIView:0x8c41c40.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84480 H:|-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d65460]   (Names: '|':Linees:0x8c82d70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d844d0 H:[UILabel:0x8d65460(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84500 H:[UILabel:0x8d65460]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d73890]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84550 H:[UILabel:0x8d73890(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d845b0 H:[UILabel:0x8d73890]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d731b0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d845e0 H:[UILabel:0x8d731b0(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84640 H:[UILabel:0x8d731b0]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d734e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84690 H:[UILabel:0x8d734e0(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84700 H:[UILabel:0x8d734e0]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d741b0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84730 H:[UILabel:0x8d741b0(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d847d0 H:[UILabel:0x8d741b0]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d744d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84800 H:[UILabel:0x8d744d0(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d84860 H:[UILabel:0x8d744d0]-(6.85714)-|   (Names: '|':Linees:0x8c82d70 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8c8aef0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x8c41c40(480)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8d847d0 H:[UILabel:0x8d741b0]-(6.85714)-[UILabel:0x8d744d0]>
```

The thing is that I don't set constraints for these labels anywhere else on my code and this debugger warning could not be less explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The warning says that you have an NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint (it derives from the autoresize automatically translated to constraints). Probably you want to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO` not only on the labels but on the vistaGris too.

Comment: thanks, but didn't help. What I did and it worked is to remove one constraint. The last gasp constraint:  -gap-|  After that it works ok. It seems this one wasn't necessary and maybe some rounding when dividing was causing the problem.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you fixed it.